# How to run 'python setup.py install' from within Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a generic python script for starting up a python app and I would like to install any dependent python modules if they are missing from the target system.  How can I run the equivalent of the command line command 'python setup.py install' from within Python itself?  I feel like this should be pretty easy, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Related: [Directly call distutils' or setuptools' setup() function with command name/options, without parsing the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2850971/2127008)

Answer (score 13):

For those, who use setuptools you can use [setuptools.sandbox](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/sandbox.py) :

```
from setuptools import sandbox
sandbox.run_setup('setup.py', ['clean', 'bdist_wheel'])
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if setup.py is in your current directory. (That may be why they refer to the first argument as "script_name", not "script_path".)

As it is currently written, it changes to the base directory but fails to also update the relative path to the setup.py, resulting in a no-such-file exception.

Comment: What exactly is being sandboxed here?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai as written [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/2234e88b7b820c40f29d7ddadc182b0f130eaa1d/setuptools/sandbox.py#L242) `Run a distutils setup script, sandboxed in its directory`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'setup.py', 'install'])
```

Comment: How to do that if setup.py is on some other path, for example in c:\foo\bar\setup.py ?

Comment: Pass in the full path as the second argument.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me (py2.7)
I have a optional module with its setup.py in a subfolder of the main project.

`from distutils.core import run_setup 
[..setup(..) config of the main project..] 
run_setup('subfolder/setup.py', script_args=['develop',],stop_after='run')`

Thanks

**Update:**
Digging a while
you can find in distutils.core.run_setup

> ```
> 'script_name' is a file that will be run with 'execfile()';
> 'sys.argv[0]' will be replaced with 'script' for the duration of the
> call.  'script_args' is a list of strings; if supplied,
> 'sys.argv[1:]' will be replaced by 'script_args' for the duration of
> the call.
> ```

so the above code shold be changed to

```
import sys
from distutils.core import run_setup
run_setup('subfolder/setup.py', script_args=sys.argv[1:],stop_after='run')
```

Comment: Unlike the top-voted answer, this one works with setup.py files not in the current directory. Tested with Python 3.6.8.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
string = "python setup.py install"
os.system(string)
```

Comment: How to do that if setup.py is on some other path, for example in c:\foo\bar\setup.py ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo apt install python-dev  # or python3-dev
pip install --user cython    # or pip3
```

Then

```
import os.path
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Shadow import *  # This is important!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        script_args=["build_ext", "--inplace"],  # Simulate CLI arguments
        cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
        zip_safe=False,
        ext_modules=[
            Extension("hello",
                      ["hello.pyx"],
                      language='c++',
                      include_dirs=[os.path.dirname(__file__)])]  # Same folder
    )
```

If you have `hello.pyx` in the same folder as `include_dirs`, then running the above script will place a `hello.cpp` and a `hello.so` (Linux) file in the same folder. Enjoy programmatically calling Cython.

Then just

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import hello
```

REF: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html

Answer (score 0):

Just import it.

```
import setup
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines.  Once imported, how do I call 'install'?

Comment: bad idea. it could have dependency imports that are not installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Way late - but if someone finds him/herself here like I did - this worked for me; (python 3.4). My script was one package down from setup.py. Note, you have to have chmod +x on setup.py, I believe.

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
parent = os.path.dirname(cwd)
os.chdir(parent)
os.system("python setup.py sdist")
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to you head of code:

```
import sys
sys.argv = ['./setup.py', 'install']
```