# Build multiple wheels at runtime

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to build wheels during runtime that contain some scripts as well as some payload data. E.g. in this example the `target` folder contains two simple builds `build_123` and `build_124` to be packaged as a wheel.

```
main_project
├── __init__.py
├── whl_util.py               # wheel building script posted below
target/
├── build_123/                # contains one build to be packaged as a whl
│   └── mypkg
|       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── data
|       |   ├── __init__.py
|       |   └── mat.json
│       └── main
|           ├── __init__.py
|           └── dumpmat.py
└── build_124/                # contains another build to be packaged as a whl
    └── mypkg
        ├── ...
```

In my scenario this wheels are used as an output format and the packaging is not the main progress. The wheel packaging should be considered as a simple IO operation that reads a build folder and outputs a wheel with no side effects other than that. To perform this task I came up with this solution:

```
# main_project/whl_util.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys
import shutil
import os

def bdist_wheel(build_dir=".", dist_dir=None):
    # backing up argv to restore them afterwards
    argv_bak = sys.argv[:]

    # clear args from running script with "bdist_wheel"
    file = sys.argv[0]
    sys.argv.clear()
    sys.argv.extend([file, "bdist_wheel"])

    if dist_dir is not None and "--dist-dir" not in sys.argv:
        sys.argv.extend(["--dist-dir", dist_dir])

    sys.argv.extend(["clean", "--all"])

    setup(
        name="mypkg",
        version=0.1,
        packages=find_packages(build_dir),
        install_requires=[],
        include_package_data=True,
        package_dir={'': build_dir},
        package_data={"mypkg.data": ["mat.json"]}
    )

    # restore args
    sys.argv.clear()
    sys.argv.extend(argv_bak)


def main():
    # Adding main method here for testing.
    # As mentioned in my actual scenario the wheels should be built as an output format at runtime
    print("BUILD 123")
    bdist_wheel("target/build_123", dist_dir="target/dist_123")
    print("BUILD 124")
    bdist_wheel("target/build_124", dist_dir="target/dist_124")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I also don't really like the way of passing parameters to `setuptools` via `sys.argv` but it seems to be the only way. However, the main issue is, that the first wheel is built normally while the second call of `bdist_wheel`/ `setup` raises an error:

```
python3 -m main_project.whl_util
BUILD 123
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/mypkg
copying target/build_123/mypkg/__init__.py -> build/lib/mypkg
creating build/lib/mypkg/data
copying target/build_123/mypkg/data/__init__.py -> build/lib/mypkg/data
creating build/lib/mypkg/main
copying target/build_123/mypkg/main/__init__.py -> build/lib/mypkg/main
copying target/build_123/mypkg/main/dumpmat.py -> build/lib/mypkg/main
running egg_info
writing target/build_123/mypkg.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to target/build_123/mypkg.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to target/build_123/mypkg.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'target/build_123/mypkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
copying target/build_123/mypkg/data/mat.json -> build/lib/mypkg/data
installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
running install
running install_lib
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg
copying build/lib/mypkg/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg/data
copying build/lib/mypkg/data/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg/data
copying build/lib/mypkg/data/mat.json -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg/data
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg/main
copying build/lib/mypkg/main/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg/main
copying build/lib/mypkg/main/dumpmat.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg/main
running install_egg_info
Copying target/build_123/mypkg.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg-0.1-py3.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/mypkg-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL
creating 'target/dist_123/mypkg-0.1-py3-none-any.whl' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel' to it
adding 'mypkg/__init__.py'
adding 'mypkg/data/__init__.py'
adding 'mypkg/data/mat.json'
adding 'mypkg/main/__init__.py'
adding 'mypkg/main/dumpmat.py'
adding 'mypkg-0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
adding 'mypkg-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL'
adding 'mypkg-0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt'
adding 'mypkg-0.1.dist-info/RECORD'
removing build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
BUILD 124
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
copying target/build_124/mypkg/__init__.py -> build/lib/mypkg
error: could not create 'build/lib/mypkg/__init__.py': No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The `no such file or directory` error suggests that the `setuptools` module keeps track of what folders it already created and assumes that these folders still exists. However after building the first wheel the `clean` script will delete the built folder (which is necessary, since `setuptools` will otherwise reuse the folder without clearing it)

My only working solution yet is to fork the process before applying `setup`:

```
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    setup(...)
    sys.exit(0)
os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

But since this seems very dirty and also my main process is very memory intensive, I'd rather avoid this method.

**So my main question:**
Is there a way to build a wheel without any side effects? Or is there a way to reset the state of the `setuptools` module after applying `setup`? In an optimal world I would like to create the wheel in an in-memory `PyFilesystem` and only write the wheel to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure *setuptools* is meant to be used this way. As far as I know *pip* and co. (*wheel*, *setuptools*, etc.) don't really have public APIs or at least no friendly ones.

The `distlib` library looks like a promising alternative with an actual API. See [*distlib*'s documentation on "Using the wheel API"](https://distlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-the-wheel-api).

If this doesn't work then I probably would give one of those a try:

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'wheel', 'pack', 'target/build123'])
```

See [`wheel pack` documentation](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/wheel_pack.html).

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'wheel', 'target/build123'])
```

See [`pip wheel` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/). And the reasons why it can't be used with API calls are noted in [the "Using *pip* from your program" section of *pip*'s documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program)

---

There is a somewhat similar question with some interesting ideas:

- [How to run 'python setup.py install' from within Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4419752/11138259)

Maybe generating a `setup.py` dynamically at run time could help.

Comment: I think the `subprocess` method is really the best of the approaches. I tried quite a lot of approaches now with `distlib` and `setuptools.sandbox` package (as suggested by your last link) but was not quite happy with the results. However I found out that in my case packing the code as `zip` also works which allowed me to build the files completely in memory.